# Which of the variables appear to be effect modifiers. When stratifying by each variable, which seem to indicate the presence of interaction?

Tags: interaction, odds-ratio, epidemiology, stratification

The following graph displays five pairs of stratified odds ratios (not from the same study) with 95% confidence intervals. For this plot, assume the confidence intervals indicate whether the stratum-specific odds are significantly different, with one estimate in the serving as the null value for the other stratum.

[image]

Based on the plot, which of the variables appear to be effect modifiers. Put another way, when stratifying by each variable, which seem to indicate the presence of interaction?
VARIABLE A: YES or NO
VARIABLE B: YES or NO
VARIABLE C: YES or NO
VARIABLE D: YES or NO
VARIABLE E: YES or NO

Comment: This appears to be a homework question and, if so, should be tagged "self-study" so that you're not just "given the answer", but useful clues so that you can find the answer *and* gain the understanding.

Comment: Please don't remove the substance of the question after getting an answer. This is not just dishonest but ruins the question for those coming down the road since the detail is missing.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question. When you posted on 
SE, you gave up ownership of the content under
[CC BY-SA 4.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing). 
If there are no answers, you may delete your own question 
(see 
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)
): just click the faint gray 'delete' at lower left (your 
account needs to be registered for this). Otherwise, the 
thread will remain according to SE's rules.

Answer (score 1):

An effect modifier *modifies* the effect of treatment. In each section of the forest plot, I expect that the x-axis "OR" shows the effect of treatment vs non-treatment in the "exposed" group versus the "unexposed" group.

For instance, if we are modeling salt-reduction counseling (treatment) versus ongoing/recurrent hypertension following an initial diagnosis of hypertension (outcome), then each stratum variable might be age (A), race (B), other comorbidities (C), etc. So for "A" (>65 y/o vs. <= 65 y/o), I see the OR is 1 for the young group and 1 for the old group, so the treatment is not only completely ineffective, but there is no difference at all between age groups.

If the variable significantly modifies the effect of treatment, we expect that the ORs and corresponding CIs are mutually non-overlapping. However, if the effect of treatment is unmodified, we expect the ORs to be relatively homogeneous within each stratum (although the width of the CI *may* be different). In that case, are there *clearly* inconsistent ORs for any variable?

Comment: @phoebehalliwell this is not what effect modificaton is. Effect modification concerns mutual overlap of the 95% CI. Consider the two possible stratified effects for, say, age: Old RR= 1.1 (95%: 0.95 to 1.21) Young RR = 0.90 (95% 0.80, 1.01). In both cases the ORs intersect the null, that RR=1, but they do not overlap the opposite's point estimate, so we can say age is an effect modifier.